# How do I mount a raid disk

Tags: centos, raid, mount, grub

So I screwed up my grub.conf file on a CentOS system and I'm in recovery right now (it's only a test dedicated server). My disks are /dev/sda1 and /dev/sdb1 (RAID 1). Now I need to mount /dev/sda1 and make changes to the grub file, however those changed need to be reflected on the second disk aswell.

How do I mount these RAID disks? I can mount one using `mount -t ext3`however it will damage the RAID array.

Comment: what kind of raid is it? mdadm ( software raid )  or do you have a hardware raid card?

Comment: @OlivierS Ah thanks it's software raid. I've found out now how to mount it, I had to make it active. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found out already, I had to make the raid active and then mount it with `mount /dev/md1 /mnt/raid`:

```
How do I mount a software RAID in the Rescue System?
The command:
cat /proc/mdstat
shows all available software RAID arrays. Normally the Rescue System assembles all autodected arrays. Should your array not be automatically started, you can manually do so with the following command:
mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
Now you can mount the just created MD device with:
mount /dev/md0 /mnt
```