# Backup data from RAID 1 disk out of its server

Tags: linux, raid, mount, raid1, md

I'm facing with a pretty easy problem in my opinion.

I've extracted a working disk from a RAID1 and I'm looking to copy only data (FS and RAID configuration doesn't matter) into another location (another FS).

My problem is **I'm not able to mount** properly this disk into another linux.

I've first looked the partition table :

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sdc
Disk /dev/sdc: 640.1 GB, 640135028736 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 77825 cylinders, total 1250263728 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1              63  1249535699   624767818+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdc2      1249535700  1250017649      240975   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdc3      1250017650  1250258624      120487+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

I've understood I should use dmraid tools. Once installed :

```
# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : 
md0 : inactive sdc1[1](S)
      624767744 blocks

unused devices: <none>
```

And some other informations :

```
# mdadm --examine /dev/sdc1
/dev/sdc1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : 8f292f54:7e5aef72:7e5ab5fd:b348fd05
  Creation Time : Mon Jun  2 03:39:41 2008
     Raid Level : raid1
  Used Dev Size : 624767744 (595.82 GiB 639.76 GB)
     Array Size : 624767744 (595.82 GiB 639.76 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Tue Feb  7 22:34:59 2012
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : a505b324 - correct
         Events : 15148


      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     1       8        1        1      active sync   /dev/sda1

   0     0       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1
   1     1       8        1        1      active sync   /dev/sda1
```

From here, I've tried to mount but I'm not comfortable with dmtools and how it's working.

```
# mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/sdc1
mount: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'

# mount /dev/md0 /mnt/sdc1
mount: /dev/md0: can't read superblock
```

I've seen some options to alter RAID array with mdadm but I only want to copy data on its filesystem before wiping them... Anyone has a clue ?

Comment: Have a look at http://serverfault.com/questions/375390/how-do-i-mount-a-raid-disk, it might help. I asked this yesterday ;-)

Comment: Good question/answer too, except I just have to run instead of assemble :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do

```
shell># mdadm --assemble --scan
```

once done, you should be able to see that md0 became active when you type

```
shell># cat /proc/mdstat
```

if it is not the case, try

```
shell># mdadm --assemble --scan --run
```

and repeat

```
shell># cat /proc/mdstat
```

to see if md0 became active.

Once md0 is active, you can mount it with

```
shell># mount /dev/md0 /mnt/sdc1
```

and recover your data by copying it wherever you want.